# Making a listview of all recorded files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I'm making an app that records files. So far I'm successful with it. 
This is the start recording method:

```
public void startRecording (){
     recorder = new MediaRecorder();
     recorder.reset();      
     recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
     recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
     recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
     if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
     {
         externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
         externalOutputPath = externalStoragePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/no_name.mp3";
         recorder.setOutputFile(externalOutputPath);
     }
     else
     {
        storagePath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        normalOutputPath = storagePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/no_name.mp3";
        recorder.setOutputFile(normalOutputPath);
     }
     recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
     recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

     try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, the file is saved as .mp3 to a certain location or SDcard or wherever. Now I need to implement something that will add every single recorded file to a listview that includes the name, duration and some more details, and if I press on the item it will play. All this in a different activity of course.

Comment: Exactly what do you need help with? What have you done so far?

Comment: Sounds like "just do it", do you expect us to write the code for you?

Comment: @Henry No, I was just hoping for some pointers on how to approach doing it. Being a completely beginner programmer, so I sometimes have difficulties on how to even begin doing it. I already googled how to read mp3 files from SDcard, but I'd much rather somehow automatically add them to the listview as they're being recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try reading files from your SDcard with [this](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a34/Directory-Browser-Application.html) and then filter to show only mp3 files with something like [this](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-implement-java-filefilter-list-files-directory). Let me know if it helps. I'd give you a better code example but you didn't post any of your own work yet.

Comment: Thank you, I was already looking at something like this but this is a better example :)